# Why does Git start a slightly different vim version than when I start it from terminal myself?

Tags: git, vim

On my Centos 8 machine I have vim and git installed. When I open vim from terminal and view version information I see a slightly different version than when git starts vim e.g. in an interactive `rebase` process.

The full version info is below but I try to summarize the differences between case 1 and 2:

- What do I mean with slightly different? Look at line 6, git starts vim `Small version` while running vim from the terminal starts `Huge version`
- bunch of different features of vim are listed

I thought well maybe I have something weird set in my global git config, but running the following yields no output:

```sh
$ git config --global core.editor
-- No Output--

$ echo $EDITOR
-- No Output--
```

```sh
$ ls -ls /usr/bin/vim*
```

Can anybody share some insight about whats going on?

#### 1 When starting vim from Terminal

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 11 2019 16:00:09)
Included patches: 1-1763
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -clientserver      +dialog_con        +find_in_path      +keymap            +modify_fname      +multi_byte        +profile           +statusline        +textobjects       +wildignore
+arabic            -clipboard         +diff              +float             +lambda            +mouse             +multi_lang        +python/dyn        -sun_workshop      +timers            +wildmenu
+autocmd           +cmdline_compl     +digraphs          +folding           +langmap           -mouseshape        -mzscheme          +python3/dyn       +syntax            +title             +windows
-autoservername    +cmdline_hist      -dnd               -footer            +libcall           +mouse_dec         +netbeans_intg     +quickfix          +tag_binary        -toolbar           +writebackup
-balloon_eval      +cmdline_info      -ebcdic            +fork()            +linebreak         +mouse_gpm         +num64             +reltime           +tag_old_static    +user_commands     -X11
+balloon_eval_term +comments          +emacs_tags        +gettext           +lispindent        -mouse_jsbterm     +packages          +rightleft         -tag_any_white     +vertsplit         -xfontset
-browse            +conceal           +eval              -hangul_input      +listcmds          +mouse_netterm     +path_extra        +ruby/dyn          -tcl               +virtualedit       -xim
++builtin_terms    +cryptv            +ex_extra          +iconv             +localmap          +mouse_sgr         +perl/dyn          +scrollbind        +termguicolors     +visual            -xpm
+byte_offset       +cscope            +extra_search      +insert_expand     +lua/dyn           -mouse_sysmouse    +persistent_undo   +signs             +terminal          +visualextra       -xsmp
+channel           +cursorbind        +farsi             +job               +menu              +mouse_urxvt       +postscript        +smartindent       +terminfo          +viminfo           -xterm_clipboard
+cindent           +cursorshape       +file_in_path      +jumplist          +mksession         +mouse_xterm       +printer           +startuptime       +termresponse      +vreplace          -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim80"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1
-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_
SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-ha
rdened-ld  -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux   -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypt -
lutil -lc
```

#### 2 When Git starts vim

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 11 2019 15:59:32)
Included patches: 1-1763
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -cindent           +cursorbind        -extra_search      +iconv             +listcmds          -mouse_netterm     +packages          -rightleft         -tag_old_static    -toolbar           +windows
-arabic            -clientserver      -cursorshape       -farsi             -insert_expand     -localmap          -mouse_sgr         -path_extra        -ruby              -tag_any_white     -user_commands     +writebackup
+autocmd           -clipboard         -dialog            -file_in_path      -job               -lua               -mouse_sysmouse    -perl              +scrollbind        -tcl               +vertsplit         -X11
-autoservername    -cmdline_compl     -diff              -find_in_path      +jumplist          -menu              -mouse_urxvt       -persistent_undo   -signs             -termguicolors     -virtualedit       -xfontset
-balloon_eval      +cmdline_hist      -digraphs          -float             -keymap            -mksession         -mouse_xterm       -printer           -smartindent       -terminal          +visual            -xim
-balloon_eval_term -cmdline_info      -dnd               -folding           -lambda            -modify_fname      +multi_byte        -profile           -startuptime       +terminfo          -visualextra       -xpm
-browse            -comments          -ebcdic            -footer            -langmap           -mouse             -multi_lang        -python            -statusline        -termresponse      -viminfo           -xsmp
+builtin_terms     -conceal           -emacs_tags        +fork()            -libcall           -mouse_dec         -mzscheme          -python3           -sun_workshop      -textobjects       -vreplace          -xterm_clipboard
-byte_offset       -cryptv            -eval              -gettext           -linebreak         -mouse_gpm         -netbeans_intg     -quickfix          -syntax            -timers            +wildignore        -xterm_save
-channel           -cscope            +ex_extra          -hangul_input      -lispindent        -mouse_jsbterm     -num64             -reltime           +tag_binary        -title             -wildmenu
   system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.virc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/virc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim80"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1
-specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_
SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux -lncurses -lacl -lattr -ldl
```

#### 3 When starting vi from Terminal

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 11 2019 16:00:09)
Included patches: 1-1763
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -clientserver      +dialog_con        +find_in_path      +keymap            +modify_fname      +multi_byte        +profile           +statusline        +textobjects       +wildignore
+arabic            -clipboard         +diff              +float             +lambda            +mouse             +multi_lang        +python/dyn        -sun_workshop      +timers            +wildmenu
+autocmd           +cmdline_compl     +digraphs          +folding           +langmap           -mouseshape        -mzscheme          +python3/dyn       +syntax            +title             +windows
-autoservername    +cmdline_hist      -dnd               -footer            +libcall           +mouse_dec         +netbeans_intg     +quickfix          +tag_binary        -toolbar           +writebackup
-balloon_eval      +cmdline_info      -ebcdic            +fork()            +linebreak         +mouse_gpm         +num64             +reltime           +tag_old_static    +user_commands     -X11
+balloon_eval_term +comments          +emacs_tags        +gettext           +lispindent        -mouse_jsbterm     +packages          +rightleft         -tag_any_white     +vertsplit         -xfontset
-browse            +conceal           +eval              -hangul_input      +listcmds          +mouse_netterm     +path_extra        +ruby/dyn          -tcl               +virtualedit       -xim
++builtin_terms    +cryptv            +ex_extra          +iconv             +localmap          +mouse_sgr         +perl/dyn          +scrollbind        +termguicolors     +visual            -xpm
+byte_offset       +cscope            +extra_search      +insert_expand     +lua/dyn           -mouse_sysmouse    +persistent_undo   +signs             +terminal          +visualextra       -xsmp
+channel           +cursorbind        +farsi             +job               +menu              +mouse_urxvt       +postscript        +smartindent       +terminfo          +viminfo           -xterm_clipboard
+cindent           +cursorshape       +file_in_path      +jumplist          +mksession         +mouse_xterm       +printer           +startuptime       +termresponse      +vreplace          -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim80"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/red
hat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/python
3.6m -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm
/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld  -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux   -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable
-new-dtags -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib64/perl
5/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lresolv -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
```

Comment: What do you mean by "git starts vim"? Do you mean starting vim from Git Bash?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf `git` starts `vim` (or any other configured editor, `vim` is just the default) when it needs to ask the user for a commit message.

Comment: Maybe? https://askubuntu.com/questions/284957/vi-getting-multiple-sorry-the-command-is-not-available-in-this-version-af

Comment: Clearly your system has two `vim`s installed. The reason you get one instead of the other will be either: you invoked (or had Git invoke) one directly, by its path, overriding the shell's search; or, when Git invokes `vim` without specifying which path, *that* shell's search path differs from your main shell's search path when *you* invoke `vim` without specifying which path.

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple versions of Vim on your system. Try `update-alternatives --display vim` to see if there are others on your system.

Another command that might help is `yum list installed | grep vim` to see what yum thinks you have installed.

Lastly, `ls -ls /usr/bin/vim*` will list all binaries installed that start with vim. On my system, I have both `/usr/bin/vim.tiny` and `/usr/bin/vim.basic`. These are both the same version, but built with slightly different options.

I think the last one is the difference on your system as well, with you invoking one when you run `vim` from your shell and git invoking a different one.

Comment: when I try to run `vi` I get something more similar to when I start vim from terminal, similar that the output of :version only differs in the "Compilation:" section. I will add that to my question

Comment: `ls -ls /usr/bin/vi*` yields `/usr/bin/vi`, `/usr/bin/view -> vi`, `/usr/bin/vim`, `/usr/bin/vimdiff -> vim`, `/usr/bin/vimdot`, `/usr/bin/vimtutor`

Comment: I don't think git is calling any of them, is there a way to actually see what git is invoking?

Comment: `yum list installed | grep vim` yields `vim-common.x86_64`, `vim-enhanced.x86_64`, `vim-filesystem.noarch`, `vim-minimal.x86_64`

Comment: From the last comment, it looks like you have both vim-enhanced and vim-minimal. This would explain the small differences in what you have. See the answer from @bk2202 for more info on what Git is doing.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke Git without specifying an editor, the default is `vi`.  On Red Hat and CentOS systems, the `vi` binary is different from `vim` and less capable, no matter what Vim versions you have installed.  On Debian and Ubuntu systems, they are usually the same binary (via symlinks with the alternatives system) and therefore installing a more capable Vim version affects `vi` as well.

If you're on a Red Hat or CentOS system and you want to use a more capable version of Vim, you should use either `vim`, `vimx`, or `gvim -f`, as appropriate, by setting the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables or `core.editor` in the Git configuration settings.  If you're working across systems, you may prefer to set the environment variables in your shell configuration based on what's available.

The difference between these is that `vim` is a console version with no X support, `vimx` is a console version with X libraries so it supports the clipboard, and `gvim` is a graphical version.  You must use `gvim -f` in an editor configuration for `gvim` so that it does not return until you've quit; otherwise, it will fork and exit immediately and Git will see no changes to the file.

Comment: Awesome answer! Another point is that Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora also ships a `/etc/profile.d/vim.sh` that has `alias vi=vim` which makes it that if you use `vi` **from the shell** you'll actually get the more featured `vim` (the "Huge" version), while other tools spawning `vi` will not have access to the alias and will get the simpler version instead...

Comment: @filbranden thats such a pet-peeve of mine—don’t lie to me about the command I’m running! :P

Comment: well the :version shows me that both are actually vim not vi, but you are probably right in that there are just more vims installed than i have imagined. The super close build times on both vim-versions made me think otherwise.

Comment: The `vim-minimal` package provides the `vi` binary.  It's confusingly named, but that's what's happening.  The program is a version of Vim, just a small one with less features.

Comment: Ok, but how come there is a difference between git starting `vi`, and me typing `vi` in the terminal? Shouldn't it yield the same output for `:version` ?

Comment: Because by default `vi` is aliased to `vim` in the shell for unprivileged users, but that doesn't affect Git..  If you run `/usr/bin/vi`, you'll see the less capable version.  Or you can run `unalias vi` and then type `vi`, and you'll also see the same version Git uses.